# How does "unpublishing" a GitHub Action from the Marketplace works? Is it possible? Are published versions safe?

Tags: github, github-actions

I couldn't find much about whether "unpublishing" a GitHub Action from the Marketplace is possible, as of Dec, 2020.

There is a lot of doc regarding "[how to publish](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace)", but couldn't find anything about unpublishing.

> *Am I using a bad keyword? Am I understand how publishing work correctly? I had assumed published actions are different from public actions available on GitHub directly, but I'm not so sure anymore.*

Also, I read https://julienrenaux.fr/2019/12/20/github-actions-security-risk/, which basically states there is a huge security issue by blindly using something like `peter-evans/create-or-update-comment@v1` without using a specific hash. But I haven't seen use of hashes anywhere so far.

Here is an example of code that we actually use in our company, in our [GitHub Action](https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/055f53390e2be17755d7a3614df3880d17e59b01/.github/workflows/deploy-vercel-staging.yml):

```
# On E2E success, add a comment to the PR, if there is an open PR for the current branch
- name: Comment PR (E2E success)
  uses: peter-evans/create-or-update-comment@v1
  if: steps.pr_id_finder.outputs.number && success()
  with:
    token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    issue-number: ${{ steps.pr_id_finder.outputs.number }}
    body: |
      :white_check_mark:&nbsp; E2E tests **SUCCESS** for commit ${{ github.sha }} previously deployed at [${{ env.VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_URL }}](${{ env.VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_URL }})
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Basically, the above article states using `peter-evans/create-or-update-comment@v1` is dangerous, because anybody can publish against the `v1` tag and update the `v1` version we're using, without us even noticing such a change. (And, from there comes all sort of dangerous thoughts, such as Secrets stealing)

The article is 1 year old, maybe things have changed since then? It's hard to believe GitHub would leave such a security hole at the heart of their Actions Marketplace. I never heard of it before and I'm quite shocked/concerned about that.

Comment: I just found https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/finding-and-customizing-actions which mentions using SHAs. `"If you need more reliable versioning, you should use the SHA value associated with the version of the action. SHAs are immutable and therefore more reliable than tags or branches. However this approach means you will not automatically receive updates for an action, including important bug fixes and security updates."`

Comment: So, long story short, GitHub Actions Marketplace has a very different purpose compared to NPM. I had assumed they were similar, but not at all. The Marketplace is only meant to reference Actions, not host any code or provide any security measures. I wrote a bit more about my findings at https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/issues/224

Comment: It only answers part of the question, I haven't found out how to "unpublish", or should I say "deindex" from the Marketplace yet. But good point.

Comment: This should explain how to unpublish: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace#removing-an-action-from-github-marketplace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there were 2 questions at hand:

1. What is the role of the GitHub Actions Marketplace?
2. How to unpublish an action published in GitHub Actions Marketplace?

About 1), unlike what I assumed, the role of the Marketplace is limited to indexing GitHub Actions, so that they're easier to find. It's very different from NPM, which is to secure the published packages so that no one can temper with them.

Because Actions are referenced using their GitHub path, an author can destroy their own action any time. Deleting their repository or marking it private are actions that will break all existing integrations right away.

- Short story: Forking and referencing actions you use using their hash/SHA **is the only way to build resilient** actions that won't break your CI when someone changes their branch/tag, or delete/hide their GitHub repository.
- Long story: See https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/discussions/223

About 2), by "unpublishing" an Action from the Marketplace, what you really do is "deindex" it, that's all. You don't destroy anything nor break any workflow, you only remove it from the marketplace, and it won't be shown anymore.

You can do so by editing your releases (on GitHub) and uncheck the "Publish this action to the GitHub Marketplace".

See https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace#removing-an-action-from-github-marketplace