# How to automatically publish a GitHub Action to the Marketplace?

Tags: github, github-actions, release, publish

I'm trying to streamline and automate publishing of my Actions to the GitHub Actions Marketplace.

I'm quite confused about how GHA works. It doesn't behave the way I thought it would.

Here is one of such actions: https://github.com/UnlyEd/github-action-store-variable/releases

And there is the associated action on the GHA Marketplace: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/store-variables

The latest version on GitHub is 3.0.7, while the latest version on GHA Marketplace is 2.1.1.

[image: GH repo releases]

[image: GHA Marketplace]

> The role of GHA is to act as an "index", nothing more. (I had been confused a while ago, thinking it was supposed to act similarly to NPM, [see discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65357990/2391795))

Using GHA [workflows](https://github.com/UnlyEd/github-action-store-variable/blob/main/.github/workflows/auto-git-release-production.yml), I automatically create tags and releases on GitHub, and I expect GHA Marketplace to reflect the "latest" version automatically. But, it doesn't.

When publishing manually, we have the option `Publish this Action to the GitHub Marketplace`, which makes me believe there is an option to also publish to the marketplace, and that it could be done automatically when creating a GitHub Release.

But, after looking for hours at different "Create GitHub Release" actions, such as https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-release and https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release, I couldn't find such option.

[image: Creating new release]

I have 2 different workflows for publishing:

- Production
- Staging (AKA "preview", "test", "beta", etc.)

For **production**, I want to automatically create a new tag (i.e: `v3.1.2`), a new GitHub Release, and publish it to GHA Marketplace. ([see current workflow](https://github.com/UnlyEd/github-action-store-variable/blob/main/.github/workflows/auto-git-release-production.yml))

For staging, I want to automatically create a new tag (i.e: `v3.1.2-rc.0`), a new GitHub Release (marked as `prerelease`) and I **don't** want to publish it to the GHA Marketplace.([see current workflow](https://github.com/UnlyEd/github-action-store-variable/blob/main/.github/workflows/auto-git-release-staging.yml))

Currently, tags and releases are created automatically and they work *relatively* well.
*(I'm still encountering issues with special tags like `latest`, and generic major version tags like `v3`, but that's another issue)*

But I couldn't find a way to automatically publish to GHA Marketplace. **Must it be a manual step?**

Comment: Well, it seems it cannot be done automatically for security reasons (2FA required), see https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5193#issuecomment-1036278907